# How do I export IIS7 site and app pool settings using Powershell and the Web Administration Provider?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, powershell

I would like to export the site settings and app pool settings for a specific site in IIS7 using Powershell so i can restore them on another server. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Web Deploy (http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) instead, and since it has a command line you can just use that from PowerShell. You could alternatively use the APIs which are managed code and can be used from PowerShell, but it should be a lot easier to just shell into the command line.